# Change nested form field value from parent component

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

Assume I have a nested form which implements CVA(Control Value Accessor).

```
// Child component which implements CVA
this.addressForm = new FormGroup({
 city: new FormControl()
 postalCode: new FormControl(null)
})
```

```
// Parent component html
<form [formGroup]= "productForm">
 <input formControlName="date">
 <address-form formControlName="addressForm"> </address-form> 
</form>

// Parent component ts
 this.productForm = new FormGroup({
  date: new FormControl(null),
  addressForm: new FormControl(null)
});
```

Now I want to patch ONLY  `city` field of addresForm so I tried:

```
// This will set other values of addressForm to null.
this.productForm.get('addressForm').patchValue({city: 'some-city'});

// This below will not work.
this.productForm.get('addressForm.city').patchValue('some-city');// error no city control.

// Another workaround is using ControlContainer instead to link to parent
Instead of this:
  // this.addressForm = new FormGroup({
  // city: new FormControl()
  // postalCode: new FormControl(null)
  //})
using this on child
this.addressForm = this.controlContainer.control as FormGroup;
and declare formGroup on Parent.
this.productForm = new FormGroup({
  date: new FormControl(null),
  addressForm: new FormGroup({city: new FormControl(null), postalCode: new FormControl(null) })
});

BUT in this workaround, writeValue method is not called on Child.
```

Since it is formControlName which holds a single value other values are reset.
So how can we set nested form field values without resetting other field's values?

In other words, how can we control nested form component fields from parents such as patching value or listening to specific field value changes?
[Stackblitz URL](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lnkh5e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: could you show writeValue function code?

Comment: sure . Here console log now showing.    
public writeValue(value: TAddressForm): void {
    console.log('writeValue', value);
    const { city, postalCode} = value || {};
    this.formGroup.patchValue({ city, postalCode}, { emitEvent: false });
  }

Comment: The problem is you are destructuring writeValue argument, when you patching value from the parent that sends object { city: 'some-city' }, then JS can't find postalCode here and sets it to undefined, so try to do that:
public writeValue(value: TAddressForm): void {
    this.formGroup.patchValue(value || {}, { emitEvent: false });
  }
and that from the parent:
this.productForm.get('addressForm').patchValue({city: 'some-city'});

Comment: unfortunately it is not the case, I call console.log('writeValue) inside this method and it is not seen on devtools.

Comment: Do you provide NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR?

Comment: yup. Everyhing is fine. It implemens ValueAccessor, the methods such as writeValue are called, if I declared formGroup on child, but using controlContainer approach, the writeValue not called.

Comment: added Stackblitz. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lnkh5e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: As I told you change writeValue patching function to this.addressForm.patchValue(value || {}); and your form will patching correctly :)
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-we8nru there is my example which I also prepared for you

Comment: this cool man. Thanks Yan Koshelev. I see that, the patchValue mechanism is taken care child form. I appreaciate! I am currently checking on my product. Will reply soon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vulgar, you has not a formGroup inside a formGroup, you has only a FormGroup with two FormControls, the last one store an object.

In general, when we work with FormGroup we can take two approachs

1.-Define the full FormGroup in the parent, and pass to the children the inner FormGroup

```
this.productForm = new FormGroup({
  date: new FormControl(null),
  addressForm: new FormGroup({ //see that adressForm is a FormGroup
     city: new FormControl()
     postalCode: new FormControl(null)
  })
});
```

Our child is a simple component -no implements controlValue Accesor

```
//declare a variable "form"
form:FormGroup
//in a input asign the variale to the form
@Input('addressForm') _ set(value)
{
   this.form=value as FormGroup
}

<!--we control the formGroup as another formGroup-->
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input formControlName="city">
  <input formControlName="postalCode">
</form>
```

And we use in parent

```
<form [formGroup]= "productForm">
 <input formControlName="date">
 <!--see that pass as @Input the formGroup-->
 <address-form [addressForm]="productForm.get('addressForm')"> </address-form> 
</form>
```

2.-Create a custom form control that manage an object {city:..postalCode:..}

```
export class CustomAddressComponent implements ControlValueAccessor,OnDestroy {
  form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    city: new FormControl(),
    postalCode: new FormControl(null)
  });
  subscription:any
  onChange = (obj: any) => {};

  onTouched = () => {};
  writeValue(obj: any) {
    this.form.patchValue(obj);
    this.subscription=this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(res=>this.onChange(res))
  }
  registerOnChange(onChange: any) {
    this.onChange = onChange;
  }

  registerOnTouched(onTouched: any) {
    this.onTouched = onTouched;
  }
  setDisabledState(disabled: boolean) {
    this.form[disabled ? 'disable' : 'enable']();
  }
  ngOnDestroy()
  {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe()
  }
```

And use in parent as

```
  productForm = new FormGroup({
    date: new FormControl(null),
    addressForm: new FormControl(null)  //<--see that is only a FormControl
  });

<form [formGroup]="productForm2">
  <input formControlName="date">
  <!--use formControlName, it's like another input!-->
  <custom-address-form formControlName="addressForm"> </custom-address-form>
</form>
```

In the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-x8qfze?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) you has the two approach. See that the form.value has in both cases the same structure

NOTE:Really to manage a FormGroup I prefer use the simple approach (use a component), using only a custom form control for "some more" than group FormControls.

NOTE2: the custom form control is made quickly only to demo propouse

**Update** Really there're anothers ways, we can, e.g. create our form like

```
  productForm = new FormGroup({
    date: new FormControl(null),
    addressForm: new FormGroup({}) //<--an empty FormGroup
  });
```

And our component create the form

```
  form:FormGroup
  @Input('addressForm') set _(value:any)
  {
     this.form=value as FormGroup;
     this.form.addControl('city',new FormControl())
     this.form.addControl('postalCode',new FormControl())
  }
```

Even use FormGroupDirective to access to a Form and create a form like

```
  productForm3 = new FormGroup({
    date: new FormControl(null), //<--see that we don't add anything more
  });
```

And use a component like

```
  form: FormGroup;
  constructor(
    @Host() private formGroupDirective: FormGroupDirective,
    @Attribute('groupName') private name
  ) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.formGroupDirective.form.addControl(
        this.name,
        new FormGroup({
          city: new FormControl(),
          postalCode: new FormControl()
        })
      );
      console.log(this.formGroupDirective.form.value);
      this.form = this.formGroupDirective.form.get(this.name) as FormGroup;
    });
  }
```

And our parent component:

```
<form [formGroup]="productForm3">
  <input formControlName="date">
  <!--see that only put our component yet add the formGroup-->
  <address-form-three groupName='addressForm'> </address-form-three>
</form>
```

I updated the stackblitz with these two cases

NOTE: I think remember another way, but I can not find the link :(

Comment: Hi Eliseo. First of all thanks for detailed answer.
Approach 1: this wont suit unfortunately.
 Reason: how can we listen to event whether form is disabled/enabled? In CVA, we have setDisabledState()

Apporach 2: It is current approach I am using and problem is I cannot change specific value of nested form. Please see on question. It resets others nested form values.

Comment: You can not use this.productForm.get('addressForm.city') because you has **no** control "city". You can use `this.productForm.get('adressForm').setValue({city:'your-city'})` -but you loose the postalCode-. About the first aproach you can disable/enable from parent or form child. The FormControls are the **same**, e.g., from parent:`this.productForm.get('address.city').disable()` or `this.productForm.get('addressForm').disable();` In child, you can use `this.form.get('city').disable()` or `this.form.disable()`

Comment: Eliseo, yes I agree with you the behavior is same, but the problem is we cannot listen to Disabled state. For example, when form enabled, the child component does some staff. The workaround would be to pass isDisabled as Input and listen via onChanges lifecycle. Another big issue is, in this case if we have valueChange listeners on Child that may break because the child component is rendered on condition so on Parent Component if I change the child value while the child value is rendered(afterViewInit) that will throw error like cannot patchValue of undefined.

Comment: Update: seems passing formGroup can also be workaround. Will post update. Thank you Eliseo!

Comment: Seems like approach 2 overall suits me. One of the downsides is, you should make sure that you correct field name since there are declared on parent component and you also use on child.

Comment: Yes, it's true and there several approach to avoid this. Some time ago I read a great article about this, but I can not find it, sorry (however I add two ways more). Another I just find is this one:https://itnext.io/partial-reactive-form-with-angular-components-443ca06d8419

Comment: Thanks! Will check it out.